# Netcat can't connect to a port from an external IP

Tags: linux, network-programming, netcat

I have 2 machines, I try to send a JSON request from machine2 to machine1.

When I do

```
echo '{"name": "app_01", "output": "THIS WILL WORK", "status": 1}' | nc localhost 3030
```

It works fine. I receive my request in my log file.
But when I try to to the same on my machine2, I have a `Connection Refused` error.

```
echo '{"name": "app_01", "output": "THIS WILL NOT WORK", "status": 1}' | nc 192.168.10.134 3030
```

My 2 machines are in the same local network.
Do you have an idea why it doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: I think receiving end should run command similar to `nc -l ip port`?

Comment: No, actually, I have a process that to that already (Sensu Client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Connection Refused" is usually caused by the following reasons:
- There is a firewall (s/w or h/w) in-between your connection
- There is nothing bound to that port
- The service bound to the port can't take anymore connections

In your case, I would check that your receiving service is bound not only to localhost but to the outbound interface (0.0.0.0)?

Comment: Yes, that was that, thanks ! It was bound to 127.0.0.1 and I needed to bound it to 192.168.10.134